# Update function in html5 canvas game isn't working properly

Tags: html5, html-canvas

Jsfiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/seekpunk/6eeKH/15/

the code :

```
if (this.collection.length > 0) {
    if (((this.collection[0].blockX + this.collection[0].blockW) >= cw) 
       || (this.collection[0].blockX <= 0)) {
        this.collection[0].blockSpeed *= -1;
    }
    this.collection[0].blockX += this.collection[0].blockSpeed;
}
```

the first block from top is drawn twin and i can't figure out why i guess the  problem is in drawing the levels can someone please help me figure out what i did wrong in my code

Comment: "How to debug my code" questions are not considered good questions on the site. Please edit the question to describe what algorithm you want to implement and why you think it's not working.

Comment: updated my question please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding blocks using `addBlocks` method every frame in function `Level1`, all your blocks are duplicated loads of times. In `Blocks.draw()`, print the size of the collection and you'll see what I mean.

Make sure you set up your level once, then change the state of it, do not add all the blocks on every frame.

Comment: thank you i followed your instruction and this is the new jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/seekpunk/6eeKH/17/ the levels are drawn fantastically thank you for your help

Comment: Glad I could help.